# copy the value of a hidden field from a button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to copy the value of a hidden text field from another button. At the moment I'm trying to simply show it with an alert when I click on the button but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ?

php:

```
echo "<p id='campoCopiar' class='btn btn-warning btn-lg paginasTotales'>Páginas totales: <b>" . $paginasTotales . "</b></p>";
echo "<input id='oculto' name='oculto' type='hidden' value='" . $paginasTotales . "'>";
```

js:

```
document.querySelector("#campoCopiar").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var oculto = document.querySelector("#oculto").value;
    alert(oculto);
});
```

The variable is defined because one line above I have another code where it shows it and it works correctly.

The call to the js file I have it at the bottom just before the closing tag of the body

Answer (score 0):

The `$paginasTotales` variable isn't declared anywhere in your code, it seems like it's empty. Maybe that's why?

Comment: In this case, shouldn't an alert still be triggered? The variable does exist because just above I have a section where it shows it and it does it correctly.

Comment: I've copied your code and in my browser I do get an alert, it's just empty bcs I haven't defined the paginasTotales variable. Perhaps try a different browser? or your current browser is blocking alerts? Your code works on my side.